# Excel 2003 - How to build my own XLA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, xla

How can you make the .xla file if you want to create your own xla? I have the code, classes, shapes, etc....what is the process to making an xla file to point to? I know that I have to put it in my program files folder, and then go through the steps to adding an "add-in" in xls...but i mean actually saving an xla file to point to....

can i simply write all this in xls and then save it as file type xla?? because i have tried to do that but I get an error that it is not a valid add in when I am in a spreadsheet trying to point to it?

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should help:

**Create an .XLA file**

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-496.html

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-62362.html

http://www.ehow.com/how_5066365_create-excel-xla-addin.html

**Creating An XLA Add-In For Excel**

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CreateAddIn.aspx

**Microsoft Excel VBA Macros. How to Create an Excel Add-in For Them**

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

**Excel VBA - install an Excel Add-in (XLA or XLL)**

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/06/excel-vba-install-excel-add-in-xla-or.html

If you are still having issues let me know...

Comment: Great list of resources Vecdid!

Comment: Glad it helps, please let me know if you have issues with implementation, have done it a few times.